# TypeORM SELECT with IN on view from jsonb

Tags: node.js, typescript, postgresql, typeorm

I have 2 tables. I do left join on them and in select I do `company.data -> 'number' as company_number,`.
Then when I want to query those data.

```
this.find({ where: { company_number: In(1,2,3) } });
```

But instead of result I have error. `QueryFailedError: operator does not exist: json = json,`

Any idea how can I solve this problem?

Comment: is `company.data` a `jsonb` field?

Comment: Yes, `company.data` is jsonb field.

Answer (score 0):

What I had to do was adding type conversion in postgres query.
So `company.data -> 'number' as company_number`.
Is now `(company.data -> 'number')::text as company_number`.

And it works almost well, but it add quotation marks around original value.
So `A` becomes `"A"`.

To fix this I used:

`(company.data -> 'number')#>>'{}' as company_number,`